# Eigenvectors calculation: a defective matrix, a zero matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a dynamical system: $\dot{\mathbf x}$= A$\mathbf x$ with $\mathbf x$= 
$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and A =
$\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ \beta & 3 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr). \beta$ real, time-independent.

I calculated the eigenvalue $\lambda$ = 3 with the algebraic multiplicity of 2.

The **first question** is about eigenvectors when $\beta = 0$ and when $\beta \neq$ 0:

1) when $\beta$ = 0, I have $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ \beta & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$.
Does this allow for eigenvectors calculation? Does it tell me anything at all?

2) when $\beta \neq$ 0, I have $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ \beta & 0 \end{smallmatrix} \bigr) \bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} x \\ y\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ = $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$, so my eigenvector is $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$ and A is defective? Is there any other eigenvector?

The **other question** is further on case 2) when $\beta$ = 3. I am to find any fixed points + their stability, but first I am wondering whether I did the above correctly. I am not sure how to approach it, thought about a trajectory expression, but I am confused by the defective A.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not really matter, it is traditional (well, in the U.S.) to put the $1$ in the Jordan form above the diagonal. I have been noticing students lately getting to the Jordan form but failing to write things in the reverse( and actually useful) order.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & \frac{1}{\beta} \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 0 \\
\beta & 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
\beta & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
\beta & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & \frac{1}{\beta} \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 0 \\
\beta & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then the exponential of $Jt$ with
$$
J =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
3 & 1 \\
0 & 3
\end{array}
\right)
$$
is
$$
e^{3t} \; \;
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and you use the second matrix identity above to finish

$$
e^{At} = 
e^{3t}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
\beta & 0
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & \frac{1}{\beta} \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
e^{3t}
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 0 \\
\beta t & 1
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
e^{3t} & 0 \\
\beta t e^{3t}& e^{3t}
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Answer (score 0):

When $\beta = 0$, you have $A = 3I$ so the eigenvectors are the standard basis and the eigenvalues are both $1$.

When $\beta \ne 0$, the matrix is not diagonalizable, it only has a Jordan form.

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvectors for $\beta\ne0$ are $[0,1]^T$, linear dependent, therefore they don’t  form a basis (not diagonalizable), thus defective.

The eigenvectors for $\beta=0$ are $[0,1]^T$, $[1,0]^T$, i.e. ,the standard basis.

The fixed points do not change for $\beta\ne0$, and they are clearly unstable since the eigenvalues are positive.